# How to manually create msxml document in IE10

Tags: xml, internet-explorer-10, msxml

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521554/xpath-in-internet-explorer-10-gone) and I understand that when dealing with an ajax response, it is possible to instruct IE10 to create an msxml document instead of a native XML document. This is in order to use legacy xpath methods such as selectSingleNode.

However, in my case I am not reading the XML from an ajax response, I am reading it from raw text in javascript. E.g., this is a code snippet that works in most browsers:

```
var xmlString = "<a><b>some data</b></a>";
vor xmlDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
```

In IE10, DOMParser returns a native XML document. What can I do differently here in order to get an MSXML document, similarly to the way it's done with ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to explicitly create an instance of the parser using `ActiveXObject`:

```
var xmlDocument = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
xmlDocument.async = 'false';
xmlDocument.loadXML(xmlString);

alert(xmlDocument.selectSingleNode('//a/b').text);
```

See also

- [What is XML DOM?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757022(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Program with DOM in JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761349(v=vs.85).aspx)

ps. if you need to test for `ActiveXObject` being available, then check out [window.ActiveXObject difference in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638981/window-activexobject-difference-in-ie11), testing for `window.ActiveXObject !== undefined` seems to work fine.