# XSLT transformation issue in IE 11

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt

I am trying to transform XML using XSLT.
    It Works Perfectly on FF , Chrome , IE upto 10.
    But in IE-11 its not Working .
    Here is a Sample code i am using.

```
function TransformXML(XmlPath, XsltPath) {
    xml = loadXMLDoc(XmlPath);
    xsl = loadXMLDoc(XsltPath);
    // code for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window){
        ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
        $('#divId').html(ex);
    }
        // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
        //alert("In");
        xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        var xmldom = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xml);
        var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
        var transformed = serializer.serializeToString(xmldom.documentElement);
        $('#divId').html(transformed);
    }
}
```

Comment: ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638981/window-activexobject-difference-in-ie11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is in `loadXMLDoc(XsltPath)`, so we need to see the code of that function. IE used to return an MSXML DOM document as `responseXML` and MSXML supports XSLT with `transformNode`. Recent IE versions return an IE DOM document as `responseXML` and don't support XSLT (nor with `transformNode` nor at all). If you want to use XSLT and load the stylesheet code with XMLHttpRequest then you need e.g.

```
function loadXMLDoc(url) {
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined')
  {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url, false);
    // request MSXML responseXML for IE
    try { xhr.responseType = 'msxml-document'; } catch(e){}
    xhr.send();
    return xhr.responseXML;
  }
  else {
    try {
      var xhr = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
      xhr.open('GET', url, false);
      xhr.send();
      return xhr.responseXML;
    }
    catch (e) {
      // handle case that neither XMLHttpRequest nor MSXML is supported
    }
  }
}
```