# Loading scripts only on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I want to load these scripts only in IE. The conditional comments aren't working because [they aren't supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx) on IE 10 or above and I'm working on IE11.

¿Any ideas?

I tried the [answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987969/how-to-load-a-script-only-in-ie), but it's giving me an error.

```
Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0138' 

Nested Script Block 

/solicitudviajes/desplazamientos.asp, line 31 

A script block cannot be placed inside another script block. 




<script type="text/javascript">
if(/MSIE \d|Trident.*rv:/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    document.write('<script src="../jquery-ui/jquery-1.10.2.js"><\/script>');
    document.write('<script src="../jquery-ui/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"><\/script>');
    document.write('<script src="../jquery-ui/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"><\/script>');
    document.write('<script src="../jquery-ui/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"><\/script>');
    document.write('<script src="../jquery-ui/ui/jquery.ui.button.js"><\/script>');
    document.write('<script src="../jquery-ui/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"><\/script>');
    document.write('<script src="../jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a server side language? it can usually pick up what browser you are using, otherwise you can use js to detect and include the scripts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987969/how-to-load-a-script-only-in-ie

Comment: I tried the answer from the duplicated question before but It's giving me an error, that's why I did this question again                                      Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0138' 

Nested Script Block 

/solicitudviajes/desplazamientos.asp, line 31 

A script block cannot be placed inside another script block.

Comment: This is a problem with ASP not validating your document. You can probably get around that using the CDATA annotation. However, ASP is a different issue from what was asked here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the browser. There are some libraries out there which do this for you. A simpler approach would be using something like this:

[How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)