# IE 11 compatibility issue with jQuery function

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I've implemented the following jQuery which is simply blanking out a textfield, when a radio button is selected. On Firefox and Chrome the function is working, but on IE11, which is actually used within the working environment it is not working - the textfield is blanked out by default.

I need some help to fix this compatibility issue.

```js
function hideMappeDigital(){
 if (jQuery("#Mappe-j_idt41-0").is(':checked')) {
  jQuery("#Mappe-Anzahl").attr("disabled", "disabled");
 }
 jQuery('#Mappe-j_idt41-0').click(function(){
  jQuery("#Mappe-Anzahl").val('');
  jQuery("#Mappe-Anzahl").attr("disabled", "disabled");
   });
 jQuery('#Mappe-j_idt41-1').click(function(){
  jQuery("#Mappe-Anzahl").removeAttr("disabled");
 });
}
```

Comment: Hi, one question per question please... And this is not JSF related as it seems.. I only see jquery code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE 11 v11 does not respect "disabled" property on inputs on a single machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790522/ie-11-v11-does-not-respect-disabled-property-on-inputs-on-a-single-machine)

Comment: In summary use `.prop` not `.attr`: `jQuery("#Mappe-Anzahl").prop("disabled", "disabled")`

Comment: Which version of jQuery? I created a StackBlitz from your code, please fork it to demonstrate your issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-overflow-ie-11-compatibility-issue-with-jquery-function

Comment: it's jQuery version 1.4.4

Comment: in StackBlitz it is working correctly. The problem is, that it is not working on the test server instance

Comment: I just observed that the radio button group is permanently inactive (h:selectOneRadio) when testing the application on the testserver

Comment: From your most recent comment, it seems that you are using JSF (Java Server Faces). This could indeed affect the issue. Please provide the relevant bits of JSF.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with

```
jQuery("#Mappe-Anzahl").attr("disabled", true);
```

Also try with

```
jQuery("#Mappe-Anzahl").prop("disabled", true);
```

Also check //need to add some CSS to look like disabled

```
jQuery("#Mappe-Anzahl").prop("readonly", true);
```

Comment: Care to add an explanation on why this would help?

Comment: @Kukeltje I am not sure, thats why I mention try--sometime the attr not work properly thats why I mention prop, this could be conflict issue too...

Comment: just tried it. I observed that the function is working localy (on IE11). But, when deploying it to a testserver, it's not working anymore, ...

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry it's only available within the intranet (btw.: don't have any permissions grant any access)

Comment: set a settimeout of 100-- if the code conflict with any other, then it will execute at last...

Comment: .prop is not working (it's not even working locally). Will try it with jQuery("#Mappe-Anzahl").attr("disabled", true); on the testserver. Thanks a lot so far! :)

Answer (score 0):

@freedomn-m answer in the comments is the right one: IE doesn't always respect boolean attributes so you need to write `disabled="disabled"` and `required="required"` for example.
Also, as of jQuery 1.6 .prop is the preferred way over .attr [read the note here on the official docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)